# Rails 4 best_in_place gem display issues with iterating through list

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, best-in-place

I followed [Railscast #302](http://railscasts.com/episodes/302-in-place-editing) to install the [best_in_place gem](https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place) for my app's shopping cart, and am now able to successfully update the item's quantity inline, as well as use the ajax success binding to update the div containing the total price for that item in my cart. However, I have a weird display issue that arises when trying to iterate over the full list of items in the cart.

When the user first lands on the cart, they see the following: [image: shopping cart with multiple items].

When trying to update the quantity of either item; however, two columns appear for each line item. The first column (in both rows) contains the  field matching the value for the first item's total, and the second column in both rows does the same for the second item's total: [image: shopping cart with stray item total fields]

This stray item continues to update properly if the quantity of the second item changes; however, **the two issues are: 1) the stray item should not be where it is, and 2) the proper item on the same line as item #2 does not update.**

Relevant code samples below, thanks in advance!

*line_items_controller.rb*

```
class LineItemsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :json 

  ...

  def update
    @line_item = LineItem.find(params[:id])
    @line_item.update_attributes(line_item_params)  
    respond_with @line_item
  end
end
```

*shopping_carts/show.html.erb*

```
<% @shopping_cart.line_items.each do |line_item| %>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="small-6 columns">
      <%= line_item.meal.name %> 
    </div>

    <div class="small-3 columns">
      <%= best_in_place line_item, :quantity, :as => :select, :collection => {"1" => 1, "2" => 2, "3" => 3, "4" => 4, "5" => 5} %>
    </div>

    <div class="small-3 columns line-item-total">
        <%= number_to_currency(line_item.total_price) %>
    </div>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

*shopping_carts.js*

```
$(function() {
  jQuery(".best_in_place").bind("ajax:success", function(data) {
    $(".line-item-total").load(location.href + " .line-item-total");
  });
});
```

Comment: With the undesired total on the screen, right click on the element and choose `inspect element`. This might give an idea of where the unintended output is coming from. Post the relevant html.

Comment: @Beartech i updated the question with some new code and screen shot as i changed the id for total line to a class. even so, inspecting the element just yields two line-item-total classes in each row.

Comment: what about your web server log? My thinking is that you are firing the JS and either it's making two calls somehow, thus the extra item, or it's the part that updated the div. I'm terrible at AJAX, so I have trouble with reading what's going on here. Normally I would use the  AJAX to call another JS that updates the `div` using another partial but it looks like you are updating the elements directly? Sorry, trying to learn here as well as answer. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to solve this. The issue was related to needing to create unique IDs for each div. This was accomplished by using the line_item id in the div id itself.

*shopping_carts/show.html.erb*

```
<% @shopping_cart.line_items.each do |line_item| %>

    <div class="small-6 columns">
      <%= line_item.meal.name %> 
    </div>

    <div class="small-3 columns">
      <%= best_in_place line_item, :quantity, :as => :select, :collection => {"1" => 1, "2" => 2, "3" => 3, "4" => 4, "5" => 5} %>
    </div>

    <div id="line-item-total-<%= line_item.id.to_s %>-container" >
      <div class="small-3 columns" id="line-item-total-<%= line_item.id.to_s %>">
   </div>

<% end %>
```

*shopping_carts.js*

```
$(function() {
  jQuery(".best_in_place").bind("ajax:success", function(data) {
    id = $(data.currentTarget).data().id;
    $("#line-item-total-" + id + "-container").load(location.href + " #line-item-total-" + id);
    $("#cart-calculations").load(location.href + " #cart-calculations");  
  });
});
```